# Can't stop a defined recursive function using Scala

Tags: scala, if-statement

I have the below function which i can't stop from looping and don't understand where i'm going wrong.

```
def takeSingleTableDrinkOrder(size: Int): String= {

var order = ""

if (size == 0) order  = "finish"

else order = {

     println("\nHow old are you?")

     var age = readLine.toInt

       if (age < 18) { 

         println("\n\nchoose from the following:\n\n"  
         + "pepsi\n"  
         + "coke\n" ) 

   var input = readLine
   input

  } else {

       println("\nchoose from the following:\n\n"  
       + "pepsi \n"  
       + "coke \n" 
       + "wine \n" 
       +  "beer\n")

  var input = readLine
  input
  }

}

 val drinkOrder = order + ":" + takeSingleTableDrinkOrder(size - 1)

  drinkOrder    
}
```

I'm new to Scala so please excuse my simple questions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
def takeSingleTableDrinkOrder(size: Int): String =
  if (size == 0) {
    "finish"
  } else {
    println("\nHow old are you?")

    val age = readLine.toInt

    val order =
      if (age < 18) {
        println("\n\nchoose from the following:\n\n"
                + "pepsi\n"
                + "coke\n")

        val input = readLine

        input
      } else {
        println("\nchoose from the following:\n\n"
                + "pepsi \n"
                + "coke \n"
                + "wine \n"
                + "beer\n")

        val input = readLine
        input
      }

    order + ":" + takeSingleTableDrinkOrder(size - 1)
  }
```

A recursive function should always have one path that does not call itself, but your call was outside the `if` and therefore was always called.

Comment: Thanks for your help